# How to merge or combine matrices row-wise to form a new matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, merge, concatenation

I have three matrices:

```
A = [1 2 3; 
     4 5 6; 
     7 8 9]

B = [10 11 12; 
     13 14 15; 
     16 17 18; 
     19 20 21; 
     22 23 24; 
     25 26 27]

C = [28 29 30; 
     31 32 33; 
     34 35 36; 
     37 38 39; 
     40 41 42; 
     43 44 45; 
     46 47 48; 
     49 50 51; 
     52 53 54]
```

I want to merge one row from `A`, two rows from `B`, three rows from `C` to get a new matrix `D`:

```
D = [ 1  2  3;
     10 11 12; 
     13 14 15;
     28 29 30; 
     31 32 33; 
     34 35 36;
      4  5  6;
     16 17 18; 
     19 20 21;
     37 38 39; 
     40 41 42; 
     43 44 45;
      7  8  9;
     22 23 24; 
     25 26 27;
     46 47 48; 
     49 50 51; 
     52 53 54]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will end up with `18` rows. You can find the rows for each of your matrices using

```
mod(1:18,6)
```

which returns

```
[1   2   3   4   5   0   1   2   3   4   5   0   1   2   3   4   5   0]
```

So you want the rows of `A` to correspond to `1` in the above vector, `B` is for `[2,3]` and `C` for `[4,5,0]`.

Initialize a matrix of zeros:

```
D = zeros(18,3)
```

put in `A`

```
D(mod(1:18,6)==1,:) = A
```

similarly for `B` and `C`

```
D(ismember(mod(1:18,6),[2,3]),:) = B
D(ismember(mod(1:18,6),[4,5,0]),:) = C
```

It's neater to make some intermediate variables:

```
n = size([A;B;C],1) 
D = zeros(n,size(A,2))

idx = mod(1:n,6)
idx_A = idx==1
idx_B = ismember(idx,[2,3])
idx_C = ismember(idx,[4,5,0])

D(idx_A,:) = A
D(idx_B,:) = B
D(idx_C,:) = C
```

Comment: First trick working. For second, subscripted assignment dimension mismatch error is shown. Idx is not vector.

Comment: @user9003011 sorry typo in the assignment of `idx`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *for* loop and *vertcat* to perform what you are requesting.

```
D=[];
for aa = 1:length(A(:,1))
     D = vertcat(D,A(aa,:),B((aa*2-1):(aa*2),:),C((aa*3-2):(aa*3),:));
end


D =

 1     2     3
10    11    12
13    14    15
28    29    30
31    32    33
34    35    36
 4     5     6
16    17    18
19    20    21
37    38    39
40    41    42
43    44    45
 7     8     9
22    23    24
25    26    27
46    47    48
49    50    51
52    53    54
```

edit: As mentioned by Sardar Usama, this code isn't efficient especially when arrays get very large. an indexing method and pre-aliquating variables is a much better method.

Comment: Read why this is not a good idea: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

To solve your particular problem, only with indexing.

```
D=zeros(size([A;B;C],1),size(A,2)) % Intializing
D(1:6:end,:)=A; % We want 1rA, 2rB, 3rC, so row of A are in row 1, 7, etc
D(2:6:end,:)=B(1:2:end,:); % 1st row of B are in row 2, 8, etc
D(3:6:end,:)=B(2:2:end,:); % 2nd row of B are in row 3, 9, etc
D(4:6:end,:)=C(1:3:end,:); % etc
D(5:6:end,:)=C(2:3:end,:);
D(6:6:end,:)=C(3:3:end,:);
```

Comment: Its highly particular Ans. To generalize the Ans, I think you might include "reshape"

Comment: What do you mean ?